# Where I can find python-igraph transitivity_undirected source code

Tags: python, igraph

I want to read how python igraph implemented transitivity_undirected function. I download the code from https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/. I think the function I am looking for is `igraph_transitivity_undirected` but I could not locate where the function body is using grep -rnw . -e "igraph_transitivity_undirected". Can anyone help explain how their code are organized and where should I look for the implementation?

Comment: If you want to see where the work is happening, you're looking in the wrong repository. All the work happens in the [C igraph library](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/02005680aebb4281f2964c6d2d8d98851fce63b9/src/triangles.c#L610).